# random sampling from spatial points in R

Tags: r, point, sampling

Can anyone help me out on the best package to sample from a spatial point dataset?

My dataset consists of a list of positions inside a region, and for each point I also have the name/number of the subregion where the point is located. I would like to make my sampling using only this dataset (for example I don't want to load a shape file with the subregions or a probability raster).

I have already made a "random" sampling for each subregion, however I am not taking into account the spatial distribution of the points inside each subregion.

I am looking for a package that would let me do both spatial random sampling as well as stratified random sampling, or some guidelines on how I can create my own code.

Comment: I will point out that if you utilize a model that creates a "spatial distribution" of points, they are no longer random. This is because for a point process to follow some sort of spatial distribution you are rejecting the Complete Spatial Randomness (CSR) assumption. If you are attempting to capture a spatial process then use a point process model or stratify otherwise, keep with a random sample. I do have some sampling functions available in the spatialEco package, including a stratified sample, that may be of use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest the [spatstat](http://www.spatstat.org/) package. Perhaps check out the [quadratresample](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spatstat/versions/1.55-0/topics/quadratresample) function. They also have several others to simulate random patterns that may fit your need (e.g. `rstrat` and `rsyst`). Random sampling should be pretty trivial to accomplish on your own (see the `sample` function in base R)

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to ArcGIS 10x, the Geospatial Modelling Environment from Spatial Ecology does a fantastic job of integrating ArcGIS and R functions to create very useful workflows. The random sampling tools are the best I have come across.
http://www.spatialecology.com/gme

Answer (score 0):

With `spsample` from library(sp) it is easy to generate random points inside a polygon or spatial.

```r
rpoints<-spsample(as_Spatial(shape),n=Numbre_point,"random")
```